# filling python dictionary error

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem while filling a list with another dictionary in a loop :

When I modify some values of the dictionary, the list always take the value of the latest dictionary modification... I don't understand why.

Here is a part of my code to help :

```
l = []
for k in dData.keys():
    baseCourbe['name'] = k
    baseCourbe['dataPoints'] = dData[k]
    l.append(baseCourbe)
```

My list `l` always takes the last value assigned to `baseCourbe`.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Just an FYI - You don't need the `keys` method here.  `for k in dData` will do just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same dictionary and modifying it over and over again. It's as if you were doing this:

```
>>> d = {'sup': 100}
>>> l = [d, d, d, d]
>>> l
[{'sup': 100}, {'sup': 100}, {'sup': 100}, {'sup': 100}]
>>> l[0]['nom'] = 12
>>> l
[{'nom': 12, 'sup': 100}, {'nom': 12, 'sup': 100}, {'nom': 12, 'sup': 100}, {'nom': 12, 'sup': 100}]
```

If you want the dicts to be different then you have to copy them, e.g.:

```
>>> d = {'sup': 100}
>>> l = [dict(d), dict(d), dict(d), dict(d)]
>>> l
[{'sup': 100}, {'sup': 100}, {'sup': 100}, {'sup': 100}]
>>> l[0]['nom'] = 12
>>> l
[{'nom': 12, 'sup': 100}, {'sup': 100}, {'sup': 100}, {'sup': 100}]
```

In the context of your code you probably want something like this:

```
l = []
for name, points in dData.items():
    baseCopy = dict(baseCourbe)
    baseCopy['name'] = name
    baseCopy['dataPoints'] = points
    l.append(baseCopy)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you append `baseCourbe` to `l`, what you're actually appending is a reference to `baseCourbe`. So when you change `baseCourbe`, the changes are reflected in the values of `l` as well.

For example:

```
>>>test = {"a":1}
>>>test[2] = 5
>>>l = []
>>>l.append(test)
>>>print l
[{'a': 1, 2: 5}]
>>>test[5] = "abcd"
>>>print l
[{'a': 1, 2: 5, 5: 'abcd'}]
```